# July 4th in relation to the Jewish calendar

Tags: history, hashkafah-philosophy, calendar, jewish-american-history

I was wondering if anyone has any sources that discuss the fact that July 4th, 1776 was 17 Tamuz 5536. Is there any correlation between the Declaration of Independence and the Destruction of Jerusalem?

Comment: https://www.torchweb.org/torah_detail.php?id=112 https://www.jewishpress.com/news/what-is-the-link-between-17th-of-tammuz-july-4th-and-lincoln/2013/07/05/

Comment: 17 Tammuz was, of course, not the date of the destruction of Jerusalem per se.

Comment: https://www.commentary.org/articles/meir-soloveichik/full-measure-devotion/